# AWS Aurora server sometimes responds with "Unknown Database: ..."

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a .NET application that executes queries on a MySQL database in Amazon Aurora RDS. The database is a MySQL 5.6 database - the version that comes with Aurora.

I execute the queries against a schema (name: flight) within the database (name: SSIMLoader). I am using the MySQL 6.9.8.0 libraries.

**edit:** The connection string points to the master server in the cluster, not to a specific server.

The error occurs when doing inserts, selects, and updates so there's no real pattern to it. Even simple select statements fail randomly.

However, we receive no such error when executing the queries through MySQL workbench.

After restarting the server, the error disappears for a few days and then returns.

We have some very intense queries that do hike the CPU up to 90% for extended periods, but the error persists even after the CPU has dropped back down to 10%.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so, how did you get past it?

Thanks in advance.

- **edit:**
  Finally got the error again:

  > MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown database 'flight'
  >   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
  >   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadOk(Boolean read)
  >   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.ChangeDatabase(String databaseName)
  >   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
  >   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
  >   at Universal.Access.Database.BaseDatabaseConnection.EstablishFactoryConnection()
  >   at Universal.Access.Database.BaseDatabaseConnection.ExecuteReader(CommandType commandType, CommandText commandText)
  >   at Universal.Core.DataModel.ExecutableDatabaseConnection.ExecuteQuery(String sqlQuery) in C:\tc-projects\universal-platform\Universal.Core\DataModel\ExecutableDatabaseConnection.cs:line 65

This is the query that was running:

> `UP-DEV | Universal.Core.Data.Importer Error finding current record, SQL: SELECT aircraft_config,updated_by,asa_flight_id,atd_utc,bay,terminal,is_cancelled,flight_number,created_at,from_iata,flight_date_utc,std_local,takeoff_time_local,is_international,is_aerocare,cobt_local,customer_atd_local,takeoff_time_utc,std_utc,atd_local,asa_state,aircraft_type,customer_atd_utc,carrier_code,updated_at,gate,service_type,etd_local,cobt_utc,flight_status,etd_utc,aircraft_rego,created_by,id,flight_date,to_iata FROM flight.departure_flight WHERE carrier_code='JQ' AND flight_date_utc='2017-01-20T00:00:00' AND flight_number='57' AND from_iata='MEL'. Database returned: Unknown database 'flight'`

Comment: I don't believe this message is actually coming from Aurora.  Or at least I suspect it may not be.  Errors from the Aurora server [should have an error number](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlexceptionmembers.html) along with the standard message, and "Unable to find database" does not seem like a standard message found in the upstream source code -- and Aurora generally uses the standard errors.  What is the *exact* wording of the error, and what's the accompanying code?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - i have edited the question to show the error as I see it in the logs.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I would agree that usually the database engines have error numbers, but as this is a "tweaked" version of MySQL built specifically by AWS, they may be hiding the numbers.

Comment: No, they are definitely not hiding the numbers.  The error code has a fixed byte position near the beginning of an error packet in the wire protocol. [*"The Amazon Aurora database engine is designed to be wire-compatible with MySQL 5.6 using the InnoDB storage engine."*](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/)  It's there, I've seen it.

Comment: Hello, we are having the very same issue with one of our services using Amazon Aurora. The issue happens at random times and is usually with a spike of 1k+ Database Connections in our Aurora statistics. Is it an active issue for you? For me i am still hunting down the root cause.

Comment: Hi @PascalParadis, we are definitely still experiencing this and we are no closer to an answer. We have tried the precise same system with a normal hosted MySQL db and have not seen the same results. Unfortunately, right now, I can't say for sure what the root cause may be.

Comment: Hello @Vaelen, are you interested to have a chat about this issue? I have created https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162530/room-for-pascal-paradis-and-vaelen for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

While I'm not sure what specifically triggers the problem (it appears that an open connection can somehow end up in a broken state on the RDS cluster side), it appears that the problem is exasperated by the aggressive connection pooling and re-use on the client side happening in the MySQL .NET Connector.

Once the problem occurs, the affected connections appear to just stay in the pool, getting arbitrarily picked back up from the pool and re-used over and over. (Quite likely related to how you see the problem continuing to randomly occur once it has started.)

Adding [`Connection Lifetime=x`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) to the connection string, x being  the time in seconds that a connection is kept alive for re-use, seems to at the very least reduce the symptoms.

Comment: +1 for symptom reduction. Unfortunately, i think due to the random nature of the issue, reproducing it will be difficult and hence it may never actually be rectified.

Comment: I've got the exact same problem and the ConnectionLifetime change has reduced it a lot but it still happens. What is it that messes up the connection in the pool and is there a solution?

Comment: @Harry My impression is that the connection gets broken internally on the RDS side, leaving little to work with in terms of troubleshooting or solving the problem for us mere users. If you get something useful out of AWS Support or otherwise figure something out, please contribute your findings.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I've been trying to get help through AWS Support with that on and off all day. Did you have any luck with various connection string settings for the connection pool such as ConnectionReset=true; ?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that this error occurs when the Aurora instance cpu is at 100%.
The connection cannot find the database specified because it cannot connect to the instance as there are no threads left with which to establish a connection.

Comment: I am in development at the moment with no production traffic. The CPU on my instances is about 5% (seems to be the resting state) and I get this error so frequently that my application can't make it through its startup code.

Comment: We have still got no idea as to why this is happening. We have not been able to replicate the error outside of our production systems and it is so sporadic now that the decision has been made to rather handle it in our code than try and decipher its origin.

Comment: I fixed the problem for now by increasing the size of my instance from medium to 2xlarge but this seems like overkill for a development environment