# intermittent "unknown database"

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, amazon-aurora

We are currently trying to troubleshoot an issue running dotnet core and EF core with an AWS Aurora (mysql) db running on RDS.

We are getting "unknown database" errors in some of our selects through EF, problem is they are fairly rare and the database obviously exists. I've added the error below, unfortunately I've only been able to find one other question opened 4 days ago ([AWS Aurora server sometimes responds with "Unknown Database: ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754711/aws-aurora-server-sometimes-responds-with-unknown-database)) but there aren't any satisfactory replies on it.

I'd appreciate any help or even some acknowledgement that it's not just me and the other guy.

```
fail: MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLQueryCompilationContextFactory[1]
  An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown database 'mydb_dev'
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadOk(Boolean read)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.ChangeDatabase(String databaseName)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown database 'mydb_dev'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadOk(Boolean read)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.ChangeDatabase(String databaseName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Did anything come to light on this, we are having the same issue when trying to create a database through the migration onto straight aws mysql.

Comment: @Paul still banging our heads against it. There seems to be a bug in the dotnet mysql connector for nested transactions, but unsure if that is related.

Comment: Hello @Paul please note that i'm having the same issue as you mentioned. I'm actually working with AWS Support to investigate further our issue. If any of you wants to discuss it a but further, you can join me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162530/room-for-pascal-paradis-and-vaelen